# Generate Crystal Reports in loop and save in a zip file and download

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, crystal-reports

I want to generate multiple reports through record id and save into a single zip file and download it. Currently im able to generate a report for single report, now I'm trying to generate reports in a loop and add into a zip file. Any assistance would be aprreciable.

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet("ReportDs");
DataTable dtSMD = GetSurveyMaster(smdId, "SMD");
ds.Tables.Add(dtSMD);
smdReport report = new smdReport();
report.FileName = Server.MapPath("~/Views/Report/smdReport.rpt");
report.Load();
string fileName = $"smdReport{smdId}_{DateTime.Now.ToString()}";
report.SetDataSource(ds);
Stream stream = report.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
```

Comment: What's preventing you from doing what you want? What error do you encounter?

Comment: I dont know how to add a "stream" of a pdf file in a zip file. Zip file doesnt exist as I have to create in memory also. I have alreay got success to save stream in a directory but I want it to add in a zip file stream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your logic above to a method called `CreateReportPdf()` to return the stream then using a library like [DotnetZip](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNetZip), you can do something like this:

```
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
{
    foreach (var smdId in reports)
    {
        string fileName = $"smdReport{smdId}_{DateTime.Now.ToString()}";
        using (var report = CreateReportPDF(smdId))
        {
            // convert stream to archive
            zip.AddEntry($"{fileName}", report.ToArray());
        }
    }
    zip.Save("YourZip.zip");
}
```

Your `CreateReportPDF` should return a `MemoryStream`

```
var ms = new MemoryStream();
stream.CopyTo(ms);
ms.Position = 0;
return ms;
```

Notice that I used your `filename` logic to generate the name of the file in the zip archive